# Apache spark to store and query json data is a good use case?

Tags: json, mongodb, hadoop, database-design, architecture

**Architecture -** A brief description about the architecture, I am working on a answering engine where people query and wait for answer (something different to a search engine). Back-end looks for automated answer or if doesn't finds the answer directly it sends out snippet to the interface with the confidence score. Whatever snippets and answers gets generated are stored in Mongodb collection. Each query asked get a unique URL and snippetid, this ids I save in Mongodb and whenever an user jumps on to the URL from other search engines, a query to fetch the data from Mongodb collection is made. At start this architecture ran well but now the data is increasing I am seriously in need of better architecture.

- Should I store data in Hadoop and can write a MR program to fetch the data.
- Should I use spark and shark preferably
- Should I stick to Mongodb
- Should I go for HBase or HIVE

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing architecture and technology selection. Though they are related these are separate notions. (You can find a couple of article I wrote about it in the past [here](http://arnon.me/2010/05/architectural-modeling-step/) and [here](http://arnon.me/2010/05/saf-mapping-forget-technology/) etc.)

Anyway to your question - generally speaking JSON is an expensive format that need re-parsing every time you fetch it (unless you always want is as a "blob") there are several other formats like Avro, Google ProtoBuff, ORC, Parquet etc. that support schema evolution but also use binary formats that are more efficient and faster to access.

Regarding choice of persistent store - that highly depends on your intended use and anticipated loads. Note that some of the options you've mentioned are aimed at completely different usages (e.g. HBase which you can use for real-time queries vs. Hive which has a rich analytical interface (via SQL) but is batch oriented)